# how to define a second id for a subClass JPA

Tags: jpa

i have 2 classes `police` and `policeArchive` each one of them have it's own id but i cannot add 2 ids to an inherit Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Police implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long idpolice;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(nullable = false)
private char nature;
..
}

@Entity
@Table
@primarykeyjoincolumn(name="idpolice")
public class PoliceArchive extends Police implements Serializable{
@Column(nullable = false)
private String idArchive;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String applicant;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date modidficationDate;
..
}
```

Comment: An inherited class MUST USE THE SAME Id as the parent. If you need separate ids then remove the inheritance.

Comment: i cannot remove the inheritance because sometimes i have to cast from police to policeArchive unless i create an adapter so there's no other way ?

Comment: No other way. Anything extending Police is also a "Police", so the id definition must stay the same

Comment: ok thank you   for ur help